# Play 2.3 writing options with Json.obj and getOrElse

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

From the activator console this works:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> val testVal = Some("foo")
testVal: Some[String] = Some(foo)

scala> Json.obj("myJson" -> testVal)
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"myJson":"foo"}
```

This also works:

```
scala> Json.obj("myJson" -> testVal.get)
res3: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"myJson":"foo"}
```

This fails:

```
scala> Json.obj("myJson" -> testVal.getOrElse(""))
 <console>:12: error: type mismatch;
  found   : Object
  required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper
          Json.obj("myJson" -> testVal.getOrElse(""))
```

But this works:

```
scala> val testVal2 = testVal.getOrElse("")
testVal2: String = foo

scala> Json.obj("myJson" -> testVal2)
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"myJson":"foo"}
```

Why does the compiler reject my third example? `testVal.getOrElse("")` evaluates to a String so why does the compiler think it is `Object` in the third example above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The arguments of `Json.obj` are repeated `(String, JsValueWrapper)`s. When you pass some variable, the compiler will attempt to implicitly convert your type to a `JsValueWrapper` using conversions that are defined in the Play JSON library (or `Writes` for your types).

The problem here is the contravariance of `getOrElse`. Since the signature of `getOrElse` is like so:

```
def getOrElse[B >: A](default: ⇒ B): B
```

This means that if you have an `Option[String]`, you can supply a value to `getOrElse` that is not a `String`, and the `Option[String]` now becomes an `Option[Any]` most likely. Because of that possibility, the compiler won't look for an implicit conversion to `JsValueWrapper`, and it fails.

The problem goes away if you use `fold` on the `Option`, which is invariant:

```
scala> val testVal = Some("foo")
testVal: Some[String] = Some(foo)

scala> Json.obj("myJson" -> testVal.fold("")(identity))
res7: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"myJson":"foo"}
```

Comment: I think I understand. I am still slightly confused as to why it works in my last example however. Why does the compiler treat the `val` differently than just putting the `getOrElse` expression inline? They evaluate to the same thing and there is no doubt that it will always be a String.

Comment: In your last example the type is inferred as `String` from the assignment. But in-line, the compiler will only infer the type from the type parameters of `getOrElse`. i.e. It's not going to look that far ahead to see if there's a literal `String` there to see if it can use an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 11):

You can also help a bit `getOrElse` method to directly define its return type

```
Json.obj("myJson" -> testVal.getOrElse[String](""))
```

Comment: This answer is a lot more readable than the `testVal.fold` option.

Comment: parsimonious and intuitive